# Content filter on exchange 2013 - not working as expected

Tags: exchange-2013, content-filter

I just setup a new ex2013 server, and we have an upstream spam filter that adds the word "[SPAM]" to the subject line if it suspect incoming spam.

I want to configure my ex2013 server to delete any incoming messages with [SPAM] in the subject line.  so I enabled content filtering on external receive connections, I added [SPAM] as a bad word phrase.

When I test sending in mail from outside with [SPAM] in the subject line the mail is still coming through.  So...am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?  (Or have I made a config error)

I assume SCL thresholds dont apply here?

Answer (score 2):

SCL thresholds do apply, actually.  [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124739%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) says:

> You can customize how the Content Filter agent assigns SCL values by
>   configuring custom words. Custom words are individual words or phrases
>   that the Content Filter agent uses to apply appropriate filter
>   processing. You configure approved words or phrases with Allow phrases
>   and unapproved words or phrases with Block phrases. When the Content
>   Filter agent detects a preconfigured Allow phrase in an inbound
>   message, the Content Filter agent automatically assigns an SCL value
>   of 0 to the message. Alternatively, when the Content Filter agent
>   detects a configured Block phrase in an inbound message, the Content
>   Filter agent assigns an SCL rating of 9.
>
> You can enter custom words or phrases in any combination of uppercase
>   and lowercase letters. However, when the Content Filter agent
>   evaluates message content, it ignores case. The maximum number of
>   custom words or phrases that can be created is 800.

You then have to [go in and tell Exchange what it should do with those messages based on the SCL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995744%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).  If you want the messages to be deleted, you need to tell Exchange to delete messages with an SCL of 9 (at least).